# Ternary operator in class property throws error

Tags: community, salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I'm going insane here with the non-specific error messages of sfdx.

`<div class="item slds-col slds-size_{! v.itemsPerRow == 1 ? '12' : '4' }-of-12">`

produces the error

`Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}`

while it should work in my opinion. Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error states your attribute value cannot mix a literal string with an expression.

You need to reformat your markup with just an expression like this:

```xml
<div class="{! 'item slds-col slds-size_'+ (v.itemsPerRow == 1 ? '12' : '4') + '-of-12' }">
```

Comment: My apologies--please ignore the previous comment. I just didn't look close enough.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because I thought that the error message refers to the part in between the brackets `{}` only.